# Debug в IIS Express / dontet.exe сам закрывается

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, отладка, asp, iis-express

Столкнулся с такой проблемой - создаю свое первое приложение asp core. При запуске в Visual Studio через дебаг через некоторое время приложение просто закрывается с кодом -1, при запуске через IIS Express не могу дебажить программу (точки остановки, контрольные значения). Подскажите пожалуйста как можно исправить проблему - либо возможность подтянуть точки остановки в VS, либо как решить проблему запуска приложения через дебаг.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```

C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (процесс 5572) завершает работу с кодом -1.
Чтобы автоматически закрывать консоль при остановке отладки, установите параметр "Сервис" -> "Параметры" -> "Отладка" -> "Автоматически закрыть консоль при остановке отладки".
Чтобы закрыть это окно, нажмите любую клавишу…

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился сам собой сменой браузера отладки на IE - почему-то Яндекс.Браузер не поддерживал отладку через IIS Express